# Why doesn't the value of a field change after form submit (JavaScript/Chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i'm building a simple Chrome extension where an user would submit his task of the day and this would be set in a Chrome "new tab" whenever he opens one.

I'm stuck on form submit. It doesn't seem to update the task div value.

the HTML looks like this:

```
    <div id="task" class="task"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <form method="post" id="taskSetting">
      <span class="subtitle">Enter:</span>
      <input type="text" name="taskInput" id="taskInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="24" placeholder="Task" />
      <button type="submit">Set</button>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
```

And the app.js part responsible for the task looks like this:

```
import getTask from './task';
import './app.css';

var taskValue = document.getElementById('taskInput').value;
.
.
.
  function setTask() {
    const taskText = getTask() + taskValue;
    
    document.getElementById('task').innerHTML = taskText;
  }

  function setupDashboard() {
    setDay();
    setTime();
    setTask();
    setInterval(setTime, 1000);
  }

  setupDashboard();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `var taskValue = document.getElementById('taskInput').value;` does not extend into the future. It simply stores the current value `""` in the variable. You need to read the value after the user has typed something into the field.

Comment: When I put this into the setTask() function and run it on the button click, I get "undefined". How should I handle the user input? I come from PHP where I could just use the HTTPRequest but from what I read it's not possible in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just realized I had this stateless, so when I turned it stateful with React did the job

```
class TextChanger extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
 super();
 this.state = {};
 }
 render() {
const task = 'task' in this.state ? this.state.task :
this.props.task;
```

and then

```
onTextChange(event) {
 this.setState({
 task: event.target.value,
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you haven't defined function that why error show....
and put setInterval(setupdashboard, 10); because you use function with this it is not a major issue but sometime
see here:

```
function setupDashboard() {
setDay();
setTime();
setTask();
setInterval(setTime, 1000);
```

}

Comment: I've set up more code including the function() and other parts of the code work, so it's not that. Pls check the comment to original post.